# unable to download data from google in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using two file. The first file is actual code and second file is reference file

```
##########################################
## Daily prices from Yahoo 
## thertrader@gmail.com - Nov. 2015
##########################################
library(quantmod)

startDate = "2014-01-01"
thePath = "D:\\daily\\data\\"
cattest <- file("D:\\daily\\error\\error.csv", open = "w") 
source(paste("D:\\Reference\\","listOfInstruments.r",sep=""))
cattest <- file("D:\\daily\\error\\error.csv", open = "a") 
for (ii in theInstruments)
tryCatch(
{
 print(ii)
 data = getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                   src = "google", 
                   from = startDate, 
                   auto.assign = TRUE,verbose = TRUE)
 colnames(data) = c("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume")
 write.zoo(data,paste(thePath,ii,".csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
}

,error=function(e){cat(ii, "\n", file=cattest)})
close(cattest)
```

I am trying to download data using following code from google but it doesn't download anything What am I am doing wrong here

```
Reference file

##########################################
## List of securities (Yahoo tickers) 
## thertrader@gmail.com - Nov. 2015
##########################################
theInstruments = c("^GSPC",
                   "SPY",
                   "QQQ",
                   "DDM",
                   "EFA",
                   "EEM",
                   "EWJ")
```

Error it seems is

```
done.
Warning messages:
1: In fname %in% c("break", "next") :
  closing unused connection 3 (D:\daily\error\error.csv)
2: In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=^GSPC&startdate=Jan+01,+2014&enddate=Jun+16,+2017&output=csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Comment: What sort of error/message are you getting?

Comment: @AK88 updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot download S&P 500 index data from Google. So either use Yahoo Finance or exclude `^GSPC` from the instruments list.

```
theInstruments = c("SPY",
                   "QQQ",
                   "DDM",
                   "EFA",
                   "EEM",
                   "EWJ")

startDate = "2014-01-01"
  getSymbols(theInstruments, src = "google",
             from = startDate)
```

New code:

```
startDate = "2000-01-01"
thePath = "D:\\daily\\data\\"
source(paste(thePath,"code\\listOfInstruments.r",sep=""))

for (ii in theInstruments){
 print(ii)
 data = getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                   src = "yahoo", 
                   from = startDate, 
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
 colnames(data) = c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
 write.zoo(data,paste(thePath,ii,".csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: i did exclude it still it doesn't download

Comment: no error can u modify ur code to save to file on windows plss

Comment: i did    still dont work ##########################################
## List of securities (Yahoo tickers) 
## thertrader@gmail.com - Nov. 2015
##########################################
theInstruments = c("DDM",
                   "EFA",
                   "EEM",
                   "EWJ")

Comment: directory r there

Comment: wat problem in that r u sure that the issue

Comment: i did that and did not work . This code use to work but i was in hospital for 3  month now it doesn't

Comment: Warning message:
In checkSkipLoopCntxt(a, cntxt, breakOK) :
  closing unused connection 3 (D:\daily\error\error.csv)

Comment: if there is error in download i capture the result in error file. Can you run this script on your system? can i run rscipt in verbose mode ?

Comment: Updated the code. Let's clean up the comments so we can start fresh.

Comment: Could not establish session after 5 attempts.
Calls: getSymbols ... do.call -> getSymbols.yahoo -> .getHandle -> new.session
Execution halted

Comment: rerun again, several times.

Comment: yahoo it seems have changed few things :(. connection get dropped regularly

Comment: yeah... there were some changes a couple months ago